# Import is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

[image]

Hi I face this error when I tried to declare import in string.xml 
why import is not a valid resource it just a string !!

Comment: Just a String is a resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are the reserved keywords in Java: `abstract` `assert` `boolean` `break` `byte` `case` `catch` `char` `class` `const` `continue` `default` `double` `do` `else` `enum` `extends` `false` `final` `finally` `float` `for` `goto` `if` `implements` `import` `instanceof` `int` `interface` `long`
`native` `new` `null` `package` `private` `protected` `public` `return` `short` `static` `strictfp` `super` `switch` `synchronized` `this` `throw` `throws` `transient` `true` `try` `void` `volatile` `while` ...using such a reserved keyword as the name for string resource is strictly illegal - because this would result in a resource descriptor alike `R.string.import`.

the solution would be - just don't use the keyword:

```
<string name="text_import">import</string>
```